# Installing Namecheap SSL certificate on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate, namecheap

I have purchased SSL certificate from Namecheap and want to import it to my AWS instance. My application runs on docker container port 80. 


1. Certificate is uploaded to ACM, and in use. 
2. Created a LoadBalancer+Target group. 
3. Configured CloudFront 
4. In Route53, pointed the A-Record to my Application LoadBalancer name.

For some unknown reason I am unable to access the URL. 
It gets redirected to Https:// but it's not accessible.

Am I missing anything here ? Your advice really appreciated on this.

Comment: How did you setup your listeners?

Comment: HTTP:80 - NA Security - NA Certificate - redirecting to HTTPS // And
HTTPS:443 - LB Security Policy - Certificate - forwarding to created Target